# Cypress waitUntil element is focused

Tags: javascript, html, cypress, pause

I have a custom command in cypress that injects an html dialog into the body. The dialog has two buttons and a textbox. Currently, cypress run, shows the dialog quickly and then moves on to the next test. I want the execution to stop at the dialog and only resume after the user has clicked one of the two buttons. How would I accomplish this so that it pauses the execution and resumes only after one of the buttons is clicked? Would I use waitUntil? How do I allow for one of two buttons to be pressed?

Comment: Observe the elements in the DOM after you clicked on the first button, perhaps the button has a locked status or something else. I am sure some changes must take place. You must get to know them and write some steps to wait for them! This will pause before pressing the second button.